# Does close() on socket on one end, closes on the other end as well?

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server

If ESTABLISHED socket (after connecting from client via `connect()`), exits and thus kernel closes all open file descriptor, what happens to the other side? If the client sends FIN and the server ACK it (which is just half-closed state), but the server tries to `read()` on that socket, what happen then? I can imagine 2 situation:

1. the socket server `read()`s on, is closed also. But in the server side there is no exit(), so noone has closed that socket at that side. So here I do not know how server ends, since its end of that socket should not be closed
2. the server socked is not closed, but it reads 0 bytes. (the return value from `read()` is simply `0`) and the rest remain on designer how to handle return value from read. But still even if the server side socket is not closed, when does the server sends *its* FIN bit? After it finishes execution (to complete full connection termination) ?

here is the statement at server side that reads from closed socket (closed at client side):

```
while ((len = read(sockfd, buf, 256)) > 0){
...
}
```

here, will it return because the `read()` reads on closed `sockfd`? or because the `read()` returns 0 and thus false the condition? (the 2 situation described above). As far as I know, if `read()` would read on closed fd, then error would be return (-1). But 0 bytes reads just return (0). So what is returned?

Comment: Closing one socket does not close another socket. 1. The socket that receives the FIN is not in a closed state until the local application closes it. It stays in CLOSE_WAIT state until then. 2. The server sends its FIN bit when it calls `shutdown()` or `close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close of a connection means that both peers agree that they don't want to communicate any more with each other. If only one peer closes the socket it just communicates with the FIN that it will no longer send any data. It also communicates to the local OS that it is no longer willing to receive any data - here `close(sock)` differs from `shutdown(sock,SHUT_WR)`.

A call to `read` in the server will return 0 if the client closed or shutdown the socket, since this meant that no more data are send from client to server. The server then might decide to also close or shutdown the socket. But might also decide to send more data to the client, since the socket is not closed yet in the server. If the server sends more data the client will respond with a RST (connection reset) since it is not expecting any more data. When receiving the RST the server side socket gets automatically closed too.

> ```
> while ((len = read(sockfd, buf, 256)) > 0){
> ```

In most cases `read` will return 0 here if the client has closed the connection. It will return -1 in case an error on the socket occurred, notably *Connection reset*. This might happen if the server has written data to the client while the client has already closed the connection (i.e. race condition), in which case the client will return with a RST. This error will be delivered on the next syscall on the socket, i.e. the `read`.

Comment: Check the edit please. Does `read()` returns -1 or 0?

Comment: And to your answer, why does RST from one side causes *automatical* termination of the other side? Isn't it that the other side has to somehow *handle* the RST response?

Comment: @milanHrabos: *"Does read() returns -1 or 0?"* - see updated answer.

Comment: @milanHrabos: *"Isn't it that the other side has to somehow handle the RST response?"* - there is no reply to a RST. The handling when receiving a RST on a socket is to close the socket since obviously the connection to the client is no longer working.

Comment: And last question. I am little bit confused, when will read() return 0. Because as I know, the `read()` blocks, when there is no byte to read (i.e. the file descriptor it reads from has no data, no bytes). So how does `read()` can return 0, when 0 means to "block"? Here the read is in while loop, but it blocks, so when it knows the `0` is *not* to block but to actually return number read?

Comment: @milanHrabos: `read` blocks only when there are currently no bytes to read but there might be in the future, i.e. when it make sense to wait for new data. If the client explicitly says that it will no longer send more data (i.e. FIN) then `read` will no longer wait for more data either - i.e. return 0.

Comment: @milanHrabos 0 does not mean 'to block'. It means end of stream. In non-blocking mode when there is no data to read it doesn't return zero, it returns -1 with `errno` set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: And how is that implemented? the "read blocks only when it expects some data"? How does kernel decide whether it *could* get some data and when not?

Comment: @milanHrabos It blocks while the socket receive buffer in the kernel is empty and no FIN has been received and no error has occurred.

Comment: Why does performing a send() after receiving a FIN cause the receiver to send an RST packet? In TCP, isn't FIN considered to be the closing of the writing end on the receiver's side? Would that not imply that the reading end is still open?

Comment: @VishalSubramanyam: In TCP the communication peer can only signal that they've stopped writing using the FIN. They might actually still want to receive data (as in one-sided socket shutdown) - or they might not want any more data (as in socket close) . The latter is signaled by sending a RST back if they receive the unwanted data.